# Possible scenarios of a flash drive corruption for FAT32 filesystem

Tags: filesystems, data-recovery, fat32, filesystem-corruption, micro-sd-card

I have an SD card which seemingly stopped working few years ago. Recently I tried recovering some data from it, and I was able to recover very little (I used Gparted). Most of the data was lost and I either couldn't access directories, or files were corrupted (~`IO error: couldn't read from pipe` or simply unreadable files with strange sizes).

Now, my question isn't about recovery; it's about the FAT32 itself - **are there ways in which corruption of a small portion of the filesystem, say some metadata, could corrupt most of the files in it? For example, tables which map file/directory pointers to the actual data on the drive?**

I'm asking because I'm using the SD card right now and it's working perfectly fine (after making a new partition map, shredding and making a new partition).

Comment: I had a FAT filesystem on an sd card that would get corrupted if I looked at it funny. Ext3 was rock solid for years, same card, same equipment. Don't use FAT

Comment: That's a good practical advice, thanks, but it's not always applicable - I can't use ext on plain media players or on older mobile phones (of which I use both xD). 
Also, I'm more interested in theoretical answers related to the way FAT works.

Comment: FAT only devices is a problem, but unless the card's bad they're generally reliable. I don't know FAT's layout (if I find a good page/image I might try for an answer) but I'd guess the actual file allocation table only has one copy & no log, if something overwrites some of it then the filenames & what sectors they're in are lost. (PS hope you tried gddrescue / testdisk / photorec for recovery, gparted had a "copy with dd" but I don't remember much else)

Comment: nah, there wasn't any important data on the card to bother recovering it. I was just glad that I could use it for storing music again :D

Answer (score 1):

Just recently went through something similar - mount the drive, and it's fine, access a particular directory, and the device suddenly is read-only.
Running fsck -n on the drive, it reported 
"FATs differ but appear to be intact. Using first FAT" and then a listing numerous errors including files size mismatches and cluster errors. 
Running fsck -y claimed to fix the problem, but did not. Figured out that fsck on Fat32 invokes dosfsck. 
Ran dosfsck --help, and one of the options was "-r interactively repair the system." 
Ran dosfsck -r /dev/sdd1 - and the very first thing it asks is 
"use the first or second FAT." 
Using the second FAT it was able to properly fix the file system.